# Variational Autoencoder on Signals

Tags: python, pytorch, signals, autoencoder

I'm trying to create a Variational Autoencoder that has to work on signal reconstruction. The dataset (torch.Size([106024, 320])) contains signals with amplitude between [-1,1]. With the following model I'm not able to see training loss reduction. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Can anyone help me?

```
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels: int, latent_dim: int) -> None:
        """
        Simple encoder module

        It predicts the `mean` and `log(variance)` parameters.

        """
        super().__init__()

        #self.flatten = nn.Flatten(start_dim=1) # torch.flatten() 
        
        # encoder
        self.enc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=320, out_features=256)
        self.enc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=128)
        self.enc3 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=hidden_channels*2)
 

        ###

        self.fc_mu = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_channels*2,
                               out_features=latent_dim)
        self.fc_logvar = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_channels*2,
                                   out_features=latent_dim)

        self.activation = nn.ELU()

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> (torch.Tensor, torch.Tensor):
        """
        :param x: batch of images with shape [batch, channels, w, h]
        :returns: the predicted mean and log(variance)
        """
        ##
        ##
        x = self.activation(self.enc1(x))
        x = self.activation(self.enc2(x))
        x = self.activation(self.enc3(x))


        x_mu = self.fc_mu(x)
        x_logvar = self.fc_logvar(x)

        return x_mu, x_logvar

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels: int, latent_dim: int) -> None:
        """
        Simple decoder module
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden_channels = hidden_channels

        ###
        
 
        # decoder 
        self.dec1 = nn.Linear(in_features=hidden_channels*2, out_features=128)
        self.dec2 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=256)
        self.dec3 = nn.Linear(in_features=256, out_features=320)

        ###

        self.fc = nn.Linear(in_features=latent_dim,
                            out_features=hidden_channels*2)


        self.activationELU = nn.ELU()
        self.activationTANH = nn.Tanh()


    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        :param x: a sample from the distribution governed by the mean and log(var)
        :returns: a reconstructed image with size [batch, 1, w, h]
        """
        x = self.fc(x)
        x = self.activationELU(self.dec1(x))
        ##
        x = self.activationELU(self.dec2(x))
        ##
        x = self.activationTANH(self.dec3(x))
        return x
```

```
class VariationalAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels: int, latent_dim: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder = Encoder(hidden_channels=hidden_channels,
                               latent_dim=latent_dim)
        self.decoder = Decoder(hidden_channels=hidden_channels,
                               latent_dim=latent_dim)

    def forward(self, x):
        latent_mu, latent_logvar = self.encoder(x)
        latent = self.latent_sample(latent_mu, latent_logvar)
        x_recon = self.decoder(latent)
        return x_recon, latent_mu, latent_logvar

    def latent_sample(self, mu, logvar):

        if self.training:
            # Convert the logvar to std
            std = (logvar * 0.5).exp()

            # the reparameterization trick
            return torch.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=std).rsample()

        else:
            return mu

vae = VariationalAutoencoder(hidden_channels=capacity, latent_dim=latent_dims)
vae = vae.to(device)
```

**TRAINING BLOCK**

```
vae = VariationalAutoencoder(hidden_channels=capacity, latent_dim=latent_dims)
vae = vae.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=vae.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=1e-5)

# set to training mode
vae.train()


train_loss_avg = []

print('Training ...')

tqdm_bar = tqdm(range(1, num_epochs+1), desc="epoch [loss: ...]")
for epoch in tqdm_bar:
    train_loss_averager = make_averager()

    batch_bar =  tqdm(train_loader, leave=False, desc='batch', total=len(train_loader))
    for image_batch in batch_bar: #for image_batch in train_loader:  # 
        #print(image_batch[0].shape)
        
        
        image_batch = image_batch[0].to(device)
        #print(torch.flatten(image_batch, start_dim = 1).shape)

        # backpropagation
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # vae reconstruction
        image_batch_recon, latent_mu, latent_logvar = vae(image_batch)
        #print(image_batch_recon.shape)
        # vae loss computation
        loss = vae_loss(image_batch_recon, image_batch, latent_mu, latent_logvar) 
        

        loss.backward()  

        # one step of the optmizer
        optimizer.step()

        print(loss.item())
        refresh_bar(batch_bar, f"train batch [loss: {train_loss_averager(loss.item()):.3f}]")

    refresh_bar(tqdm_bar, f"epoch [loss: {train_loss_averager(None):.3f}]")

    train_loss_avg.append(train_loss_averager(None))
```